Strengthening of Frankl's union-closed sets conjecture: An algebraic approach
Let $\mathcal F$ be a union-closed family of subsets of $[n]=\{1,2,...n\}$ and $n$ real numbers $x_1,x_2,...,x_n\geq 1$.

Conjecture: There exists $k\in [n]$ such that:
$$\sum_{k\in A,A\in \mathcal F}\prod_{i\in A}x_i\geq x_k\sum_{k\notin A,A\in \mathcal F}\prod_{i\in A}x_i$$
($k$ could be chosen differently for different choice of $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$).

For $x_i=1, \forall i\in [n]$, then the above conjecture become: there exists $k\in [n]$ such that the number of sets in $\mathcal F$ contains $k$ is not smaller than the number of ones does not, which is equivalence to Frankl's union-closed sets conjecture. That conjecture is trivially true for power set of $[n]$, when both side is equal to $x_k\prod_{i\neq k}(x_i+1)$ for all $k\in [n]$.
We could also consider the intersection formulation:

Let $\mathcal G$ be a intersection-closed family of subsets of $[n]$ and $n$ real numbers $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\in [0,1]^n$. Then there exists $k\in [n]$ such that:
$$\sum_{k\in A,A\in \mathcal G}\prod_{i\in A}x_i\leq x_k\sum_{k\notin A,A\in \mathcal G}\prod_{i\in A}x_i$$

This is equivalence to the above conjecture by taking the complement of all sets in $\mathcal F$ and inverse of all $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$. But it seems to be the better formulation because $[0,1]^n$ is compact and if it true for $n$, then the Frankl's union-closed sets conjecture is true for all intersection-closed families of subsets of $[m],m\leq n$, by taking $x_i=1$ if $i\in [m]$ and $x_i=0$ if $i>m$.
The lattice formulation is quite similar to the intersection formulation, but here I have a slightly stronger conjecture:

Let $L$ be a finite lattice and a non-negative weight function $w$ on elements of $L$ which satisfies: $w(a)\leq w(b)$ if $a\geq b$ and $w(a)w(b)\geq w(a\vee b)w(a\wedge b)$. Then there exists a join-irreducible element $j$ such that:
$$\sum_{j\leq a}w(a)\leq w(j)\sum_{j\nleq a}w(a)$$

Have any one of those conjectures been known? And I also would like to see the solution of those conjectures in non-trivial special cases, or counterexamples, if exist.
